# Image loaded by JS, click to put in a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple placeholder div:

```
<div id="holdImage">

</div>
```

and then I have a section where I'm using a search bar to call a function via JS which grabs images from a database and loads them into a container.

This works and the images are loaded like so:

```
function appendIMages(url, id, name, style) {
        return '<div><div class="md-card md-card-hover">         <div class="gallery_grid_item md-card-content">                                 <a href="https://images.s3.com/' + url + '" target=_blank>                                     <img class ="uk-align-center" src="https://media.siteTest.com/thumbnail/' + url + '" alt=""></a>                               <div class="gallery_grid_image_caption">                                   <span class="gallery_image_title uk-text-truncate">' + name + '</span> <span>' + style + '</span> </div></div></div></div>';
    }
```

So this works successfully, if I type an image name or description the search fires off and the images are loaded in after a couple of seconds. My question is this:

How can I make it so that when I click one of the loaded images, instead of opening it up in a page (with the URL in the address bar) it simply places the image into my holdImage div?

Comment: 1) remove the `a href` link 2) handle a "click" event on the img tag using JS, and then in that event handler copy the tag into the div

Comment: That brings up one small issue: The href link is needed to be captured to get the high resolution image of the URL but I'm only using the thumbnail to show on this page

Comment: @TomN. Isn't that `https://images.s3.com/' + url` ?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio yes that link is to the hi res version, the img source is to the thumbnail that is shown on the page for the viewer in this case

Comment: "href link needed to be captured"...so probably you just need to put that URL somewhere else...when do you want that URL to be used, exactly, if not when clicking on the picture?

Comment: You can just overwrite the click event with that functionality.

Comment: @ADyson I only want that URL to be attached to the photo for the sake of sending a form (the url will be saved in a database and emailed)

Comment: so you could put the URL into a hidden field in whatever form you are using (it's not shown here)

Comment: If the url refers to an actual image file, use the url as the src of an image tag you insert into the page? If you are forced to use a hyperlink and nothing else, have the hyperlink `_target` an iframe on your page instead of `_blank`.

Comment: I've tried ```function handleImage() {
            var $img = $("imageResult").children("img").clone();
            $("#holdImage").append($img);
        }``` with an onclick on the image tag but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: What is `$("imageResult")`? Can't see what that would select, from your code. Also I would guess it's not selecting anything, because it's probably supposed to be `$("#imageResult")` or maybe `$(".imageResult")`, unless you literally created a non-standard `<imageResult>` HTML tag in your page.